# Contents of folder have disappeared

Tags: filesystem

Twice in the last week the entire contents of a folder have disappeared when I start up my computer. The folder contains over 100 GB of files, including all my work files. It's the first folder in the root directory of my hard disc. I'm running 10.9.5 on a 27" iMac. I have been able to restore all the files using Time Machine, but it's time-consuming so it would be much better to solve the fault that's causing this in the first place

Comment: Do you have Adobe Creative Cloud? If so, get the latest update - the last one was seriously broken & would delete the first folder alphabetically on the boot drive [though it was usually a hidden one starting in . ]

Comment: I do have Creative Cloud. The first folder on the drive, the one causing problems, was called ' Work', i.e. with a space a the start to force it to the top of the list.

Comment: That will be it then - space files above . alphabetically

Comment: Thanks. I'm in the middle of restoring my files, but after that I'll try updating Creative Cloud. I think I'll rename the folder as well, just to be on the safe side!

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in a recent Adobe Creative Cloud update (version 3.5.0.206), causing the first folder, alphabetically, to be deleted from the user's boot drive.

It was first noticed by Backblaze, as their backup structure creates a folder that is often at the top of the list, `.bzvol`

As your folder was called `Work`with a space at the head, that will have filed it to the top instead of any 'dot' folder.

Backblaze recommends creating a new folder called .adobedontdeletemybzvol by typing the following in Terminal `sudo mkdir /.adobedontdeletemybzvol`, however, this wouldn't work in your case, as space will file above a .

The bug has been fixed & a new update released by Adobe, but in the meantime, creating a new folder starting 'space a' would be safe… maybe `adobedontdeletemywork` would be appropriate ;-)

Refs:
ArsTechnica - [Warning: Bug in Adobe Creative Cloud deletes Mac user data without warning](http://arstechnica.co.uk/apple/2016/02/warning-bug-in-adobe-creative-cloud-deletes-mac-user-data-without-warning/)
Backblaze helpdesk - [.bzvol is missing](https://backblaze.zendesk.com/entries/98786348)

Comment: I'll create a file as you suggested. For a while now Creative Cloud has been launching at startup and instantly crashing, which I found very annoying. In the last few days, it's changed to launching at startup and NOT crashing.